# ERROR: No primary or single unique constructor found for class [Ldsawmain.entity.vo.TagVO;

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm new to Springboot and when I use Postman to do test, I got this ERROR:No primary or single unique constructor found for class [Ldsawmain.entity.vo.TagVO;

SpringBoot Version: 3.1.2

Here is the class

**TranslationController**

```
package dsawmain.controller;

import com.mysql.cj.util.StringUtils;
import dsawmain.common.jsr303Group.DefaultGroup;
import dsawmain.common.jsr303Group.IgnoreDetailGroup;
import dsawmain.common.response.ErrorInfo;
import dsawmain.common.response.Result;
import dsawmain.common.response.StatusCode;
import dsawmain.common.utils.AuthUtils;
import dsawmain.common.utils.FuzzyQueryUtils;
import dsawmain.common.utils.RegexUtils;
import dsawmain.entity.bo.TranslationBO;
import dsawmain.entity.dto.TranslDetailDTO;
import dsawmain.entity.mysql.Tag;
import dsawmain.entity.mysql.Translation;
import dsawmain.entity.mysql.User;
import dsawmain.entity.vo.TagVO;
import dsawmain.entity.vo.TranslationVO;
import dsawmain.entity.vo.WordVO;
import dsawmain.service.serviceInterface.*;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameters;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag(name = "TranslationController",
        description = "翻译管理")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TranslationController {

    @Value("${constant.like-thresholds}")
    private int likeThresholds;

    @Value("${constant.default-contributor}")
    private String defaultContributor;

    private final WordService wordService;

    private final TranslationService translationService;

    private final TagService tagService;

    private final RegexUtils regexUtils;

    private final FuzzyQueryUtils fuzzyQueryUtils;

    private final FuzzyWordService fuzzyWordService;

    private final AuthUtils authUtils;

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public TranslationController(WordService wordService, TranslationService translationService,
                                 TagService tagService, RegexUtils regexUtils,
                                 FuzzyQueryUtils fuzzyQueryUtils, FuzzyWordService fuzzyWordService,
                                 AuthUtils authUtils, UserService userService) {
        this.wordService = wordService;
        this.translationService = translationService;
        this.tagService = tagService;
        this.regexUtils = regexUtils;
        this.fuzzyQueryUtils = fuzzyQueryUtils;
        this.fuzzyWordService = fuzzyWordService;
        this.authUtils = authUtils;
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    @Operation(summary = "addTranslation", description = "添加待翻译词的释义")
    @Parameters({@Parameter(name = "Translation", description = "释义"),
                 @Parameter(name = "Word", description = "待翻译词"),
                 @Parameter(name = "Tags", description = "标签分类"),
                 @Parameter(name = "HttpRequest", description = "Http请求")})
    @PostMapping("/add_translation")
    public Result addTranslation(@Valid TranslationVO translationVO,
                                 @Valid WordVO wordVO,
                                 @Validated(IgnoreDetailGroup.class) TagVO[] tagVOS,
                                 HttpServletRequest request){
        String translation = regexUtils.removeExtraSpace(translationVO.getTranslation());
        String word = regexUtils.removeExtraSpace(wordVO.getWord());

        if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(translation) || StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(word)){
            return Result.err(new ErrorInfo(StatusCode.INVALID_PARAMETER.getResultMsg(),
                                            StatusCode.NOT_FOUND.getResultCode()));
        }

        HashSet<String> tags = new HashSet<>();
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(tagVOS)){
            for (TagVO tagVO : tagVOS) {
                String tag = tagVO.getTag();
                tag = regexUtils.removeExtraSpace(tag);
                if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(tag)){
                    continue;
                }
                tags.add(tag);
            }
        }

        TranslationBO translationBO = new TranslationBO();
        translationBO.setTranslation(translation);
        translationBO.setWord(word);
        translationBO.setLikes(1);
        translationBO.setDeleted(false);
        translationBO.setDate(new Date());
        translationBO.setFuzzyWord(fuzzyQueryUtils.hanzi2Pinyin(translation));
        translationBO.setTags(new ArrayList<>(tags));
        translationBO.setContributor(defaultContributor);
//        translationBO.setDetail(translationVO.getDetail());

        String token = authUtils.getTokenFromRequest(request);
        String uuid = authUtils.getUUIDFromToken(token);
        if(uuid != null){
            User user = userService.queryUser(uuid);
            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(user)){
                translationBO.setContributor(user.getUsername());
            }
        }

        ArrayList<TranslDetailDTO> details = new ArrayList<>();
        translationBO.setDetails(details);
        if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(translationVO.getDetail())){
            TranslDetailDTO detailDTO = new TranslDetailDTO();
            detailDTO.setDetail(translationVO.getDetail());
            detailDTO.setDate(new Date());
            detailDTO.setContributor(defaultContributor);
            detailDTO.setContributor(translationBO.getContributor());
            details.add(detailDTO);
        }

        Translation returnTranslation = null;

        try{
            returnTranslation = translationService.addTranslation(translationBO);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return Result.err(new ErrorInfo(StatusCode.ERROR.getResultMsg(), StatusCode.ERROR.getResultCode()));
        }
        return Result.suc(returnTranslation, "添加成功");

    }

    @Operation(summary = "queryTranslation", description = "查找符合条件的释义")
    @GetMapping("/query_translation")
    public Result queryTranslation(@Valid @RequestBody @Parameter(name = "Word", description = "待翻译词") WordVO wordVO){
        String word = regexUtils.removeExtraSpace(wordVO.getWord());
        if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(word)){
            return Result.err(new ErrorInfo(StatusCode.INVALID_PARAMETER.getResultMsg(),
                    StatusCode.INVALID_PARAMETER.getResultCode()));
        }

        List<TranslationBO> translations = null;
        try {
         translations = translationService.findTranslations(word, likeThresholds);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return Result.err(new ErrorInfo(StatusCode.ERROR.getResultMsg(), StatusCode.ERROR.getResultCode()));
        }

        return Result.suc(translations, "请求成功");
    }
```

**TagVO**

```
package dsawmain.entity.vo;

import dsawmain.common.jsr303Group.DefaultGroup;
import dsawmain.common.jsr303Group.IgnoreDetailGroup;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class TagVO {

    //    @NotNull(message = "数据不能为空")
    @Size(max = 100, min = 1, message = "数据长度不合法", groups = {DefaultGroup.class, IgnoreDetailGroup.class})
    private String tag;

    @Size(max = 1000, min = 1, message = "数据长度不合法", groups = {DefaultGroup.class})
    private String tagDetail;
}
```

**WordVO**

```
package dsawmain.entity.vo;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class WordVO {

    @NotNull(message = "数据不能为空")
    @Size(max = 100, min = 1, message = "数据长度不合法")
    private String word;
}
```

ErrorLogs

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for class [Ldsawmain.entity.vo.TagVO;
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getResolvableConstructor(BeanUtils.java:268) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:221) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
```

[PostmanArguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sN91.png)

And I'm confused with this ERROR, I have search it but can't find way to solve it:(

I have tried the @ModelAttribute annotation but it can't solve this problem
Can someone give me some advise?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing query parameters in postman, but I don't see an annotation @RequestParam. It's should be @RequestParam("word") String wordVO etc. according to your postman request or if you need @Valid and object WordVO then use @RequestBody @Valid and send json.